# Attribute is not visible via joins function but in sql it work fine

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

First one is the native SQL query which is going fine but on active record it is giving not showing  nothing regarding player table. Player.name attribute is not visible although I have given access to both Batsman and Player model file

```
SELECT  
    players.name, batsmen.*  
FROM 
    batsmen 
INNER JOIN 
    players ON players.id = batsmen.player_id 
WHERE 
    league_id = 13

Batsman.joins(:player).where('league_id = ?',13).select('players.name')
```

Here are the models

```
 class Batsman < ActiveRecord::Base   attr_accessible :fours,:name, :siz, :ave,:batsmenViaLeagues, :match, :league_id, :bestf, :fifty, :hights, :hundred, :innings, :nout, :player_id, :runs, :sr, :zero  belongs_to :player  has_many :leagues


class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :image, :name   end
```

Comment: how about it you change it to Player.joins(:batsmans).where("batsmans.league_id =?", 13).select('name')

Comment: and why doesnt your Player model have an association listed (has_many :batsman) ?

Comment: tried this one to still same result .....

Comment: now it is showing Player model contain and ignoring batsmen model attribute.

Comment: did you add the has_many :batsman association to the Player class?

Comment: yes i have added association still same problem

Comment: are you trying this out in your console? and can you append .to_sql at the end and post the output

Comment: yes I am trying it on console